# Machine learning. SVM algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I want to work with machine learning in *Mathematica*. Are there any SVM algorithms implemented in Mathematica anywhere? Or any other algorithms for machine learning? With positive and negative database of [HOG descriptors.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients)

Comment: May you could i) give us a reference ii) give it a shot?

Comment: There's this http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/neuralnetworks/ 35GBP for students. Haven't used it myself I usually export the data and handle it in matlab since I have the neural networks package for matlab. It makes me cry every time EDIT: Can't find anything about SVM in the Mathematica neural networks package, perhaps it doesn't even have it

Comment: What do you mean by "positive and negative database"?

Comment: Are you testing HOG fetures on SVM method? what's your dataset, how about the real performance of Mathematica's implementation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of Version 10 , Mathematica has a built in function *Classify*, which implements support vector machines and some other common machine learning algorithms.

```
trainingset = {1 -> "A", 2 -> "A", 3.5 -> "B", 4 -> "B"};
classifier  = Classify[ trainingset, Method -> "SupportVectorMachine"];
```

Answer (score 21):

The Mathematica Journal has [a nice article on SVM's](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/SupportVectorMachines.html): *A Flexible Implementation for Support Vector Machines*, with an accompanying notebook and .m file providing an SVM implementation.

Comment: Calls to the defunct `RandomArray` can be replaced with identical ones to `RandomReal` in the example SVM notebook.

Comment: There's a (newer?) version of the package on google code: http://code.google.com/p/prpackage/source/browse/t/draft/classify/MathSVM.m

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for a break down of this code?

Comment: The link seems lost, do you know where to download a pdf version?

Comment: @HyperGroups The web archive has a couple of snapshots of this page. I also found the PDF [here](https://livingsystems.kaust.edu.sa/publications/detail/pub-2006-fis). But why would you want it? SVMs are already a built-in method of Classify.

Comment: Thanks, this week  I happen to learn and test SVM again, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277238/training-stuck-problem-about-svm-in-classify  @SjoerdC.deVries  Matheamtica's SVM worked badly  for me, that's sad story.