# Why Mathematica's Classify gives 100% accuracy on FashionMNIST dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Tested on Mathematica 13.2

```
resource = ResourceObject["FashionMNIST"]
trainingData=ResourceData[resource,"TrainingData"];
testData=ResourceData[resource,"TestData"];
fe:=N[255-Flatten@ImageData[#,"Byte"]]/255&
trainingData1=MapAt[fe,trainingData,{All,1}];
testData1=MapAt[fe,testData,{All,1}];

model=Classify[trainingData1,Method->"GradientBoostedTrees",PerformanceGoal->"Speed"]

cm=ClassifierMeasurements[model,testData1];
acc=cm["Accuracy"];
```

You can also try other methods like

`model=Classify[trainingData1,Method->"SupportVectorMachine",PerformanceGoal->"Speed"]`

I think 0.9 is a correct value for SVM.

[image]

We can gain about 100% accuracy on TestData which is questionable in machine learning area.

The sota performance is about 90% for traditional machine learning methods.

http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#

95% accuracy for neural networks methods.

https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist

The following test shows the dataset in Mathematica is somewhat different from that of github version, I don't know why.

Load method of the public dataset of FashionMNIST can see
[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277238/training-stuck-problem-about-svm-in-classify)

[image]

Comment: Where did you use the trained classifier on the test data?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau 100% accuracy in training is also an abnormal thing. See update.

Comment: You did not pass `Classify` the labels to the training set. So whatever it is doing is not well defined. Might be classifying each item as its own class. 100% correct, no problems. I'm voting to close this since there is not a clear indication of why any different result should be expected.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Hello, I think you can test it, because `trainingData=ResourceData[resource,"TrainingData"];` has labels.

Comment: Shouldn't you be the one to test it correctly? I mean, it's your question.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think I've tested rightly, I mean your comment is misguided, and is talking nonsense, because you say the data didn't gives labels, however, the training data has labels.

Comment: My comment was in no way misguided. Look at the edit history. You will see that it appeared two minutes after you changed the post to add a test on the actual test set. Which means I was working on the comment when it appeared and did not see the change. Your current test very likely is correct.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Never mind, your first comment is useful, because I see some close votes before, that confuses me. It's ok now.